# How to get code coverage for instrumentation tests in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I didn't find the option "Run with Code coverage" option for the instrumentation tests which are written under androidTest folder. But whereas I can see it for JUnit test cases which are written in test folder.

Can anyone tell me how to get the coverage for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use jacoco

Comment: @TariqulIslam I am using the same and with that I can get coverage report only for JUnit test cases and not for instrumentation test cases. The option "Run with code coverage" itself is not visible for instrumentation test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JaCoCo](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) library.

To do it add

```
plugins {
    jacoco
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        enableUnitTestCoverage true
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
```

in module build.gradle file.
Add task which is generating JaCoCo report from .ec and .exec files. Here's an example:

```
tasks.register('instrumentationCodeCoverage', JacocoReport) {

reports {
    html.required.set(true)
    xml.required.set(true)
}

classDirectories.setFrom(
        fileTree(project.buildDir) {
            include("**/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/**")
            exclude(
                    '**/R.class',
                    '**/R$*.class',
                    '**/BuildConfig.*',
                    "**/*Application.*",
                    '**/Manifest*.*',
                    '**/*Test*.*',
                    '**/android/**/*.*',
                    '**/androidx/**/*.*',
                    '**/airbnb/**/*.*',
                    "**/di/**/*.*",
                    '**/*Dagger*.*',
                    "**/*Screen*"
            )
        }
)

sourceDirectories.setFrom(fileTree(
        dir: project.projectDir,
        includes: [
                "src/main/java/**",
                "src/main/kotlin/**"
        ]))

executionData.setFrom(
        fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/test-results/instrumentation_results", includes: ['*.ec']))
}
```

**Please remember to adjust paths to your project.**

And then you can simply run `./gradlew instrumentationCodeCoverage` from terminal.

Here's example [pull request](https://github.com/appunite/Loudius/pull/199/files) in open source project with implemented code coverage for instrumentation tests.

Answer (score -2):

So by your comment i assumed that you setup successfully jacoco in your gradle. Now please change or add below material in your **app gradle:**

```
coveralls {
    jacocoReportPath = "${buildDir}/reports/coverage/debug/report.xml"
}
```

The above code make your coverage report in **app/build/report/..** And you will get two folder including other. **AndroidTest and tests** folders. In AndroidTest folder you get **coverage** folder and browse **index.html** you will get coverage report of **instrumentation** test result. Same as **tests** folder explore it and browse **index.html**.

Now the main part. You have to write below code in your a**pp gradle**

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest','connectedAndroidTest']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    // The lines below make sure we can report against Kotlin and exclude some Android Stuff
    def fileFilter = [
            '**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*',
            '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*'
    ]
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/classes/", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec', 'outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec'
    ])
}
```

After successfully sync you will see a play button beside **task jacocoTestRepor...** Hit it and select first one like Run yourProject [jacoco]

Comment: I got this error:
> Could not find method coveralls() for arguments [build_1zu29e1klokv2pznkw7wfaje3$_run_closure2@db0e891] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: The answer is incomplete. Android Gradle Plugin has no "coveralls" extension. It is an extension of a third-party plugin. So you must apply that plugin to use this.

Comment: september 2021, jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec is not being generated when you enable testCoverageEnabled true, looks like it is now generated in outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/*.exec, but not sure, not working any way.

AGP v7.1.0-alpha05
Kotlin v1.5.10